# AngularJS , pushing empty element

Tags: angularjs

Im quite new with angular. What am i freaky about is that following code is showing empty buttons (edit/delete) even if it looks empty (on start) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="todoCtrl">

<h2>todo</h2>

<form ng-submit="todoAdd(item)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput" size="50" placeholder="Add New">
    <input type="submit" value="Add New">
</form>

<br>

<div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
   <span ng-bind="x.todoText"></span><button id="#edit" ng-click="edit(item)">edit</button><button ng-click="remove(item)">delete</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.todoList = [{}];

    $scope.todoAdd = function(item) {
        $scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput);
        $scope.todoInput = "";
    };

    $scope.remove = function(item) {
        var index = $scope.todoList.indexOf(item);
        $scope.todoList.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.edit = function(item) {
        //function
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And also can somebody to help me after clicking on edit to push todoText to input and change caption of addnew to save? and afterthen change it to addNew again?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you ask for Angular2 or AngularJS? It looks like AngularJS code, but you used **angularjs** tag, and write Angular2 in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line

```
$scope.todoList = [{}];
```

to

```
$scope.todoList = [];
```

Then, it wouldn't show you empty line.

```
//Full code.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="todoCtrl">

<h2>todo</h2>

<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput" size="50" placeholder="Add New">
    <input type="button" value="{{actionName}}" ng-click="todoAdd()" />
</form>

<br>

<div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
   <span>{{x.todoText}}</span><button id="#edit" ng-click="edit(x)">edit</button><button ng-click="remove(item)">delete</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.todoList = [];
    $scope.actionName = 'Add';

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {
     if($scope.actionName === 'Add'){
        $scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput});
        $scope.todoInput = "";
     } else {
        var index = $scope.todoList.indexOf($scope.temp);
        console.log('index: ' + index);
        $scope.todoList.splice(index, 1, {todoText:$scope.todoInput});
        $scope.actionName = 'Add';
     }
    };

    $scope.remove = function(item) {
        var index = $scope.todoList.indexOf(item);
        $scope.todoList.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.edit = function(item) {
        $scope.todoInput=item.todoText;
        $scope.temp = item;
        $scope.actionName = 'Save';
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow. great. and what about that edit? Can u give me a hint please?

Comment: Just to change content of "TODO TASK"

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: Will you please create a jsfiddle of it ?

Comment: this is what i wanted? :) and how to make edited input empty after then? :)